# Tar files starting with the same pattern

Tags: awk, grep, find, tar

I have some log files named :

- 2016-02-10_03-52.log
- 2016-02-10_04-43.log
- 2016-02-10_02-13.log
- ...
- 2016-03-15_07-03.log
- 2016-03-15_09-08.log

Basically the pattern is :
YYYY-MM-DD_.log

I would like to create a tar of all files starting with the same pattern like :

- 2016-02-10.tar
- ...
- 2016-03-15.tar

The thing is that I don't know the pattern in advance only its structure.

I don't know how to search for files starting with the same (unknown) pattern .

Any help much appreciated.
Thank you

As per "Nominal Animal" solution below :

export LANG=C LC_ALL=C
find . -name '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]**' -printf '%f\n' | sed -e 's|*.*$||g' | sort | uniq | while read NAME ; do
  find . -name "${NAME}_*" -printf '%p\n' | tar -cJf "${NAME}.xz" -T - --no-unquote
done

Comment: You have to have some limitation to the pattern. say "it starts with `2016`,followed by a `-`, which is followed by a 2 digit month, followed by a 2 digit day of the month, followed by string `_log`. Otherwise, you can not filter out the files that you want. Otherwise your question is too vague

Comment: I updated my question above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that `tar` has an "append" option (`-r`), you can Keep It Stupid Simple:

```
for file in *.log; do tar -rf "${file%%_*}.tar" "$file" ; done
```

You can't include the `z` option to compress the logs with this particular approach (`tar: Cannot update compressed archives`) but boy is it simple.

Add robustness to globbing pattern according to your needs, of course.  This version assumes that *all* `.log` files should be tarred in one archive or another.

Comment: Works too, but much slower since it opens/closes the archive for each file.
thanks

Answer (score 3):

Here is a very simple two-step process to do exactly this.

First, use `find` to generate the list of all files that should end up archived. Use `sed` to generate the archive name for each. Filter the output through `sort` and `uniq` to ensure you have the names for all archives you need. For example:

```
find . -name '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]_*' -printf '%f\n' | sed -e 's|_.*$||g' | sort | uniq
```

Note that we use `%f` format above, to get the file names only, not the full paths.

Next, we pipe that through a small bash loop that reads each archive name, using `find` again to find all log files, piping that list to `tar` generating the archive.

For running such commands, I like to ensure we are using the C/POSIX locale (no localized error messages or other formatting). That is done by setting `LANG` and `LC_ALL` environment variables to `C`. So, the entire command sequence I'd use is

```
export LANG=C LC_ALL=C
find . -name '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]_*' -printf '%f\n' | sed -e 's|_.*$||g' | sort | uniq | while read NAME ; do
    find . -name "${NAME}_*.log" -printf '%p\n' | tar -cJf "${NAME}.tar.xz" -T - --no-unquote
done
```

The `-J` parameter in `-cJf` refers to XZ compression (it is fast and good, you probably do want that); I like to read `-cJf` as "create XZ archive file". The `-T -` means files in each archive are supplied from standard input, and `--no-unquote` means the file names are raw, not quoted.

Note that the pattern of the archive names is very suitable for globbing here. (That is, that we can supply it to `find -name ...`.) If the pattern contained `*`, `?`, `[`, or `]`, we'd need to escape them. Doable, but annoying. The OP has chosen the filename pattern extremely well, in my opinion.

Comment: Just fixed typos and it worked fine.
Thank you very much

export LANG=C LC_ALL=C
find . -name '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]_*' -printf '%f\n' | sed -e 's|_.*$||g' | sort | uniq | while read NAME ; do
  find . -name "${NAME}_*" -printf '%p\n' | tar -cJf "${NAME}.xz" -T - --no-unquote
done